# How can I switch SpriteKit scenes after I load data and ensure GameCenter successful sign in?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-center, dispatch-async

I am using SpriteKit and currently have the user opening the app to a landing screen which signs the user into GameCenter and loads important game data that will be displayed in the following menu scene (display name, level, etc.)

How can I check to make sure everything loads before moving to the next scene?

I tried testing using a simplified version below but it never seemed to be run despite being in the update function.

```
override func update(_ currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    // This doesn't seem to ever be called.
    if(GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().isAuthenticated) {
        let transition = SKTransition.fade(with: UIColor.clear, duration: 1.0)
        let scene = Menu(size: (view?.bounds.size)!)
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
        self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
        print("Changed to Menu scene")
    }

}
```

It's possible that what I'm looking for is an asynch dispatch to display the menu scene after the appropriate data can be pulled and populated on that scene - and show the landing scene in the meantime?  I'm not entirely sure how that works, or if it is even the right solution. Advice here would be greatly appreciated.

But why does the update function not call that if statement test?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this - The above code DOES actually work on a real device. It turns out it only does NOT work on the simulator.

Comment: You need to reset your game center account in the simulator to get it to work.  You probably hit declined 3 times when doing your various tests so it set it to permanent decline